# Adding to Room database

Tags: java, android, database

I'm trying to add data into my database but I'm not sure how to get the method to execute. I have created a Data accessing interface and an insert method already. I could be wrong but I'm also not sure if I am inserting the right fields. It's my first time using room. It's the `addToFavourites` method at the bottom into the "mFavorites" onSetClickListener.

*Movie class added below

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String KEY_EXAMPLE = "hNCmb-4oXJA";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_URL = "key";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private MovieDataBase database;
    ArrayList<TrailerRequest> mTrailerList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movie_detail_actvity);
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_iv);


        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        mTrailerList = new ArrayList<>();


        /* database instance */
        database = MovieDataBase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());


        ImageView mFavourites = findViewById(R.id.fav_image_view);
        ImageView mPlayTrailer = findViewById(R.id.trailer_image_view);



        // String intents for catching the data (String constants) from Main activity for displaying data in the detail activity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String posterUrl = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_URL);
        String title = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.TITLE_TEXT);
        String overview = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.OVERVIEW_TEXT);
        String releaseDate = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.RELEASE);
        String voteAverage = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.VOTE_AVERAGE);
        final String movieId = intent.getStringExtra(MOVIE_ID);


        // Detail activity title TextView
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);
        // Detail activity OverView TextView
        TextView overViewText = findViewById(R.id.plot_synopsis_text_view);
        // Detail activity ReleaseDate TextView
        TextView releaseTextView = findViewById(R.id.release_date_text_view);
        // Detail activity user ratings TextView
        TextView voteAverageTextView = findViewById(R.id.user_rating_text_view);

        TextView movieIdTextView = findViewById(R.id.movie_id);


        // Load Detail activity ImageView using Picasso
        Picasso.get()
                .load(Utils.buildPosterUrl(posterUrl))
                .fit()
                .centerInside()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .error(R.drawable.sample_7)
                .into(imageView);


        // set data on to views
        textView.setText(title);
        overViewText.setText(overview);
        releaseTextView.setText(releaseDate);
        voteAverageTextView.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.user_rating_tv), voteAverage));
        movieIdTextView.setText(movieId);


        mFavourites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 addToFavourites(args????)//I don't know what to do here 
                Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Added to Favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mPlayTrailer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playTrailer();
            }
        });

        mReadReviews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Show Reviews", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }



    private void playTrailer() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + KEY_URL));
        startActivity(intent);

    }


    private void addToFavourites(final Movies movies) {
        AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                database.movieDao().insert(movies);
            }
        });
    }



    @Dao
    public interface MovieDao {
        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        void insert(example.android.popularmoviesvolley.Models.Movies[] movies);

        @Delete
        void delete(Movies[] movie);

        @Query("DELETE FROM movie_table")
        void deleteAllMovies();


        //This is where we get all movies displayed in the recycler view (COME BACK TO THIS!!)
        @Query("SELECT * FROM movie_table")
        LiveData<List<Movie>> getAllMovies();


    }
```

@Entity(tableName = "movie_table")
public class Movies implements Parcelable {

```
@PrimaryKey
private int id;

private String mId;

private String mOriginalTitle;

private String mPosterPath;

private String mOverview;

private String mReleaseDate;

private String mVoteAverage;


public Movies(String id, String posterPath, String originalTitle, String overview, String release_date, String voteAverage) {
    this.mId = id;
    this.mPosterPath = posterPath;
    this.mOriginalTitle = originalTitle;
    this.mOverview = overview;
    this.mReleaseDate = release_date;
    this.mVoteAverage = voteAverage;


}


@Ignore
public Movies(Parcel parcel) {
    mId = parcel.readString();
    mOriginalTitle = parcel.readString();
    mPosterPath = parcel.readString();
    mOverview = parcel.readString();
    mReleaseDate = parcel.readString();
    mVoteAverage = parcel.readString();
}

@Ignore
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(mId);
    dest.writeString(mOriginalTitle);
    dest.writeString(mPosterPath);
    dest.writeString(mOverview);
    dest.writeString(mReleaseDate);
    dest.writeString(mVoteAverage);
}

public static final Creator<Movies> CREATOR = new Creator<Movies>() {
    @Override
    public Movies createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Movies(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Movies[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Movies[size];
    }
};

@Ignore
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}


public String getmOriginalTitle() {
    return mOriginalTitle;
}

public void setmOriginalTitle(String mOriginalTitle) {
    this.mOriginalTitle = mOriginalTitle;
}


public String getmOverview() {
    return mOverview;
}

public void setmOverview(String mOverview) {
    this.mOverview = mOverview;
}

public String getmReleaseDate() {
    return mReleaseDate;
}

public void setmReleaseDate(String mReleasedate) {
    this.mReleaseDate = mReleasedate;
}

public String getmPosterPath() {
    return mPosterPath;
}

public void setmPosterPath(String mPosterPath) {
    this.mPosterPath = mPosterPath;
}

public String getmVoteAverage() {
    return mVoteAverage;
}

public void setmVoteAverage(String mVoteAverage) {
    this.mVoteAverage = mVoteAverage;
}

public String getmId() {
    return mId;
}

public void setmId(String mId) {
    this.mId = mId;
}

//Database ID
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: what is `movieDao()`? What is this `insert`method?

Comment: Dao (Data accessing Object). The insert  just a simple insert method for SQLite but this time using Room. I can show you the whole github coz im sick of this project. :(

Comment: People can't tell you if you insert data correctly if you don't show what the data class looks like and how it's inserted. For now the code you posted is only for the GUI

Comment: I see what you mean. I've added the Dao interface at the bottom does it help or should i add the Movie object too?

Comment: the question rather is, what is `Models.Movies` (which probably should be called a `Models.Movie`)?

Comment: @pureskill75 `MovieDao` and `Models.Movies` are the relevant part; the rest is noise.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I've added the Models.Movies below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> addToFavourites(args????)

Well it looks like your addToFavourites method takes in a Movies object, so make sure that object is annotated with @Entity and has a @PrimaryKey (unique across all movies). Then pass it in.

I also notice you have two insert statements in your DAO taking in a Movie object. I THINK this is right:

```
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(example.android.popularmoviesvolley.Models.Movies[] movies);
```

So remove the other one

Then in your RoomDatabase class, make sure you have something like:

```
  @Database(entities = {Movies.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
  public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
     ...
  }
```

If this doesnt answer your question, update your post and show your Movies class.

**Edit**

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String posterUrl = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_URL);
    String title = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.TITLE_TEXT);
    String overview = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.OVERVIEW_TEXT);
    String releaseDate = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.RELEASE);
    String voteAverage = 
    intent.getStringExtra(Constants.VOTE_AVERAGE);
    final String movieId = intent.getStringExtra(MOVIE_ID);

    Movies movies = new Movies(movieId, posterUrl, title, overview, 
    releaseDate, voteAverage);

     mFavourites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             addToFavourites(movies)//I don't know what to do here 
            Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Added to Favourites", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've included everything in the post now including the Models.Movies class, I've also removed the other insert statement. Add favorites definitely takes a movie object but i just don't know how yo pass it in.

Comment: I am sorry, your question doesn't make a lot of sense. There isn't enough information. To pass a variable to a method, you simply put the variable in the parenthesis. Do you mean to ask "how do I instantiate a Movies object to pass into the method?"

Comment: Yes exactly that? (Sorry my whole project is failing and I have IDE problems and code solution problems)

Comment: Edited my answer to show an instantiation of your class, and passing that to the addToFavourites method.